# Setting image for UINavigationitem (Leftbarbutton item) in ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I m trying to setting image for UIBarButtonItem using the below code. But it appears as a blank image in the navigation bar. please help me to resolve the problem. i m entirely new to ios.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:38.0/255.0 green:126.0/255.0 blue:202.0/255.0 alpha:0.5]];
UIBarButtonItem *lftbarbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cross_Icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(additem)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:lftbarbtn];
```

thank u in advance.......

Comment: Are you sure about the image `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cross_Icon.png"]`

Comment: Your code is fine. I think problem is with your image name. Check for that.

Comment: The image name is fine.

Comment: i achieved the output using the below code. 


    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cross_Icon.png"];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    [btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Cancelaction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *lftbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=lftbtn;

Comment: But anyone plz explain why is not possible using

  UIBarButtonItem *lftbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:img   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelaction)]; 
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=lftbtn;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(popToBack)];      //create the left bar button

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;   //assign into navigation item

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:125.0/255.0 green:90.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1];   //set the tint color

 [leftBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor purpleColor],  UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    //text color


-(void)popToBack
{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

in another choice

```
UIButton *leftbutton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[leftbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftbutton addTarget:target action:@selector(buttonAction)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 31)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 5, 50, 20)];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:13]];
[label setText:title];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[leftbutton addSubview:label];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: leftbutton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;

-(void) buttonAction
{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: thankz for ur help.i have got the answer by using UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: leftbutton];

but can u give the way to  initialize the image to uinavigationitem using the below method. Bcoz i have tried it in my code. But the image is displayed as a blank space.


UIBarButtonItem *lftbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:img style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonaction)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=lftbtn;

Comment: i m new to ios. i m currently learning to use uinavigationcontroller.
can u plz tell y it is not possible using the below method

 UIBarButtonItem *lftbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:img style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonaction)];

Comment: oh k k in case u need any help cal me on karthik.saral@gmail.com (chat),

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the navigation bar directly. Use the current view controller's navigation item property to set the UIBarButtomItems. Make sure you are actually using a navigationController to set these properties.

Comment: Thankz for ur response. But i m using the current view controller's navigation item property only.Here my current view controller is EmployeeListTableViewController . i have assigned it as the root view controller of UINavigationController in app delegate itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *ReqMenuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
ReqMenuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,32,32);
[ReqMenuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ReqMenuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(somemethodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *MenuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:ReqMenuBtn];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:MenuButton];
MenuButton = nil;
ReqMenuBtn = nil;
```

Comment: this will work 100%...im using always this code..if you want more ask me.